# How to add css classes on wix's html elements?

Tags: velo

Given a Wix website with actived Tools > Developer Tools.

[image]

Given I created a file mystyles.css with code :

```
.red { background-color: pink; color: #B10000; }
```

**How to add the class `red` to my Wix HTML elements ?**

Answer (score 2):

That's not a big deal.

Open up add html element and just put your html code into it.

You can do it by click [Add]-[More]-[Html Code] on your left.

Select "code" between two options and copy paste your code.

For example,

```
<html>
<style>
  .red {
    background-color: pink;
    color: #B10000;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div class="red">I'm red!</div>
</body>

</html>
```